# Туррон, торро, турро - як правильно?

Tags: вживання-слів, іншомовні-слова

В супермаркетах на цінниках вказана назва "туррон".

[Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%83%D1%80%D1%80%D0%BE)  містить статтю "Турро":

> Турро́ або торро́ (кат. torró, вимова літературною каталанською
>   [tu'ro], у Валенсії вимовляється [to'ro]) — типова страва кухні
>   каталанських країн, зокрема валенсійської кухні. Турро популярний
>   також в Іспанії, іспаномовна назва — турро́н (ісп. turrón).

Якщо я правильно зрозуміла, то залежно від того, з якої мови робити переклад, правильні будуть всі три назви — турро, торро та туррон. Підтвердження цього припущення в інших джерелах не знайшла.

Яке слово варто вибрати для вживання, якщо в словниках української мови їх немає? Чи сміливо можна використовувати всі три варіанти?

Answer (score 1):

На жаль, на українській Вікіпедії часто бракує інформації (хоч саме в цьому випадку, мені здається, там все пояснено), тому давайте заглянемо на [англійську](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turr%C3%B3n), де Вашому питанню присвяченний цілий маленький розділ:

Ці солодощі відомі під однаковими назвами в різних країнах. В Іспанії це туррон ( turrón), в Каталонії торро (torró), в Італії торроне (torrone) тощо. Тобто, якщо ми траннслітеруємо назву цього смаколика з італійської мови, то отримаємо варіант "торроне", а якщо з іспанської, то "туррон" і обидва варіанта будуть правильними і означатимуть одне і те ж. Прикладами такої транслітерації кулінарних страв є [Паста алла карбонара](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0) - італ. Pasta alla carbonara, [фокача](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0) - італ. focaccia тощо.